# Android - Switch does not display the programatically updated values for text on/off

Tags: android, switch-statement

I am updating programatically a switch using the setTextOn/setTextOff methods and the values seem correctly updated when I look at the textOn/textOff values of my switch object in debug mode but the switch keeps displaying "ON"/"OFF" in the emulator.

```
    switch.setTextOn("abc");
    switch.setTextOff("xyz");
    switch.setShowText(true);
```

Note that I have ShowText attribute as true in xml as well.

I have a button in my activity that calls the code above in OnClick. What I have noticed though is when I put the above code directly in my activity OnCreate method it works fine.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you getting the switch object if I may ask. `Switch switch= findViewById(R.)` ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am using indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setTextOn()` and `setTextOff()` does not redraw/refresh the layout. There is no good way to do this.

You can try

`switch.requestLayout()` or

`switch.setChecked(switch.isChecked())`

after you call `setTextOn()`

but these may or may not work

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer I have tried but it does not work :/